# Meaning of "opps" and "come out of retirement"

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of *opps* and *come out of retirement*?

> Whats the longest you've gone without having sex?
>
> 3 years.
>
> wo
>
> And get this, I've only slept with 2 women in my entire life. Was a save it till you're married guy... 1st girl I was engaged to.
>
> Had plenty of opps before and after her. I really like my current girl so I decided to come out of retirement.

Comment: These usages of "opps" and "come out of retirement" are both Too Localised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opps is short for *opportunities* here.

Come out of retirement means in this case to stop being willingly (or unwillingly) celibate.

Comment: something that confuses me still is, if you say he's unwillingly celibate means he wants to have sex? But in this case he seems to not want to have sex until he's married?

Comment: @Theo I based that on your question from yesterday on which I commented.  It does seem that he wanted to wait, but based on "Was a save it till you're married guy... 1st girl I was engaged to" that ship has sailed (he was waiting, but all signs point to that he had sex with the girl he was engaged to, and she was his first).

Answer (score 2):

opps = opportunities

"come out of retirement" in this context means getting interested in other opprtunities